# Почему не работает ответ от inline_keyboard в Telegram Bot?

Tags: php, telegram-bot, telegram

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему когда я нажимаю на inline кнопку, мне не приходит ответ "Кнопка нажата" в телеграм.

Возможно с функцией sendTelegram что-то не так?

Или я не правильно обрабатываю callback_data и callback_query ?

```
<?php
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), TRUE);

$data = $data['callback_query'] ? $data['callback_query'] : $data['message'];

$message = mb_strtolower(($data['text'] ? $data['text'] : $data['data']),'utf-8');

define('TOKEN', 'MY_KEY');

$query_data = $data['data'];

if ($message == '/start') 
 {
 
    $method = 'sendMessage';
    $send_data = 
    [
        'text'   => 'Тест inline: ',
        'reply_markup' => 
        [
            'inline_keyboard' => 
            [
                [ 
                    ['text' => 'Кнопка 1', 'callback_data' => "button1"]
                ],

                [
                    ['text' => 'Кнопка 2', 'callback_data' => "button2"]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ];
}
    


if ($query_data == 'button1') 
 {
 
    $method = 'sendMessage';
    $send_data = 
    [
        'text'   => 'Кнопка 1 нажата',
    ];
}

$send_data['chat_id'] = $data['chat']['id'];

$res = sendTelegram($method, $send_data);

function sendTelegram($method, $data, $headers = [])
{
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, [
        CURLOPT_POST => 1,
        CURLOPT_HEADER => 0,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' . TOKEN . '/' . $method,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($data),
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array_merge(array("Content-Type: application/json"), $headers)
    ]);   
    
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return (json_decode($result, 1) ? json_decode($result, 1) : $result);
}
?>
```

Comment: А сообщения получить удаёться?

Comment: Я получаю запись "button1" в переменную $query_data. Но сам текст "Кнопка нажата" в телеграм не приходит =(